# Using InStr method to check if string exists in a filename

Tags: string, vba

Retrieving files from a specific folder. I want to iterate through the folder and if a file contains a specific word, then put that info in a corresponding area. I am using the InStr function and Dir. StrFile = Dir is throwing an error and I think it's because I'm using the "Dir" function earlier in the code, but I am not sure how else to make it work. Below is my code. Thank you for the help.

```
Sub retrieveFiles()
StrFile = Dir("\\ldnfi82saua\groupRates_e\Simp\CCARArchive\ICA\*crmr_s*")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    If InStr("Internal1", Dir(StrFile)) = 1 Then
        Debug.Print StrFile
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
StrFile = Dir
Loop
MsgBox Count
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Instr(StrFile, "Internal1") > 0 Then`... The 1st string argument is the string being searched, and the 2nd is the string sought. If `Instr... > 0`, the string sought was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close in what you tried.  This code will do what you need:

```
Sub retrieveFiles()
   Dim strFile As String
   Dim Count As Integer

   strFile = Dir("\\ldnfi82saua\groupRates_e\Simp\CCARArchive\ICA\*crmr_s*")

   Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      If InStr(1, strFile, "Internal1") > 0 Then
         Debug.Print strFile
         Count = Count + 1
      End If

      strFile = Dir
   Loop

   MsgBox Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Literally what I said 15 min ago :)